# Use installed plugin in Nativescript Vue

Tags: vue.js, plugins, nativescript

I am having some issues with plugins. I am installing plugins with npm and I can see that they are added to package.json and package-lock.json, but I am not sure how to integrate them into my application. An example is this:

I am trying to use this plugin: https://github.com/transferwise/currency-flags

I have installed the plugin using: npm install --save currency-flags

But I don't know how to apply it, as just adding `<Label class="currency-flag currency-flag-usd"></Label>` does not work.

Any help, please? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Install a plugin with 'use'. Read [here](https://vuejs.org/api/application.html#app-use)

Comment: I don't understand exactly how that works honestly

Comment: or you can import 'currency-flags/dist/currency-flags.css'

Comment: Where and how should I import 'currency-flags/dist/currency-flags.css' please?

Comment: where you mount app or target component

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to modify your component as you would any other Vue project.

Add these lines (for your example):

Example.vue

```
<template>
<div class="currency-flag currency-flag-usd"></div>
</template>
```

In your main.js file:

```
import 'currency-flags'
```

The issue here is the plugin you've selected is mostly CSS based.  It may or may not work well with Nativescript.

You could also just copy in the files directly to your project and access them that way.  For example, copying `src/flags/aed.png` to whatever images folder in your project and then accessing it directly.